# How to update a screen from another screen, both in different class with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to update the HomeScreen from the LoginScreen. There is a label in the HomeScreen that should be updated when the login button is pressed. In other words, when I press the login button on the LoginScreen, it should display "Welcome Mr" plus the user name.

this is my main.py code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


Builder.load_file('home.kv')
Builder.load_file('login.kv')
Builder.load_string(
"""
<ManagerScreen>:
    LoginScreen:
        id: login
        name: 'login'
    MDScreen:
        id: register
        name: 'register'
    HomeScreen:
        id: home
        name: 'home'

""" )
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)  


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def log_in(self):
        username = self.ids.username.text
        pwd = self.ids.pwd.text

        home_screen = HomeScreen()
        home_screen.ids.lab.makup = True
        home_screen.ids.lab.text = "[color=ff0000]Bienvenu Monsieur {}[/color]".format(username)

        self.parent.current = 'home'



class ManagerScreen(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ManagerScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return ManagerScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

login.kv:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    MDRelativeLayout:
        MDCard:
            size_hint: .5, .4
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            MDTextField:
                id: username
                hint_text: "Nom d'utilisateur"
            MDTextField:
                id: pwd
                hint_text: "Mot de passe"
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Log In'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.5}
                on_press: root.log_in()
            MDTextButton:
                text: "Créez un compte si vous n'en avez pas!"
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.5}
                on_press: root.parent.parent.current = 'register'
```

home.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils

<HomeScreen>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: first.height
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: first
                text: "Ecran 1"
                on_press: sm.current = 'firstscreen'
            MDRaisedButton:
                id: first
                text: "Ecran 2"
                on_press: sm.current = 'secondscreen'
        ScreenManager:
            id: sm
            Screen:
                id: firstscreen
                name: 'firstscreen'
                MDRelativeLayout:
                    MDCard:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        md_bg_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#3e55c9')
                        MDLabel:
                            id: lab
                            markup: True
                        MDRaisedButton:
                            id: buttontext
                            text: 'importer fichier'

            Screen:
                id: secondscreen
                name: 'secondscreen'
```

But when I run my code, it can't modify the Label

I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

In your `log_in()` method, the line:

```
home_screen = HomeScreen()
```

creates a new instance of `HomeScreen` that is unrelated to the instance of `HomeScreen` that is created through your use of `Builder`. So when you do:

```
home_screen.ids.lab.text = "[color=ff0000]Bienvenu Monsieur {}[/color]".format(username)
```

you are changing the `text` of a `Label` that is not in your GUI.

The fix is to access the instance of `HomeScreen` that is in your GUI. You can do that through the `ScreenManager`:

```
home_screen = self.manager.get_screen('home')
```

So your`log_in()` method should look like:

```
def log_in(self):
    username = self.ids.username.text
    pwd = self.ids.pwd.text

    # home_screen = HomeScreen()
    home_screen = self.manager.get_screen('home')
    home_screen.ids.lab.makup = True
    home_screen.ids.lab.text = "[color=ff0000]Bienvenu Monsieur {}[/color]".format(username)

    self.parent.current = 'home'
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer, I liked it. 
But in the case of a large project requiring several screens, I would have to put each screen in a python file and then call them in a single main.py file. But this method doesn't work if the screens are in different files. In this example, if the login screen is in a login.py file and the home screen is in a home.py file, how can I change the Label in the home.py screen from the login.py screen?

Comment: This has nothing to do with what files your classes are defined in.